# Unsupported operand

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to code, area of triangle using python and it's showing unsupported operand

```
height= print(float(input("Enter height ")))
base=print(float(input("Enter base ")))
area=float(height*base)/2
print('Area of triangle is: ', area)
```

error message

area=float(height*base)/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: You do not need to print `input` statements

Comment: `print` prints its arguments to screen and returns `None` so your first two assignments make `None`

Comment: You are assigning `print` to `height` and `base`. Just use `height = float(input("Enter height "))`

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `print()` in the first 2 lines because it returns a `None`, which you cannot add, - ,x,/ etc... So remove it -

```
height = float(input("Enter height "))
base = float(input("Enter base "))
area = (height*base)/2
print('Area of triangle is: ', area)
```

Edit - You could remove the float call for the area because it is gonna be a float anyway.

Comment: Just to note, the call to `float` in the definition of `area` is also unnecessary; the product of two `float`s is a `float`, and a `float` divided by an `int` is a `float`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right